# How to get all properties in class, which inherits from base class, decorated with a certain decoration

Tags: typescript, reflect-metadata

I am trying to get all properties that are decorated with certain decorator. I am trying to use `reflect metadata` for this, but it doesn't work properly if class inherits from another class which also has decorated property.

Problem is that target in decorator method is always base class. This means that when pulling out data from `Reflect.getMetadata` which brings out all properties, not only for specific class.

Lower screenshot from [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdvmml?file=src/app/app.component.ts) shows problem.

[image: screenshots]